# Converting money formatted strings to floats

Tags: php, regex, floating-point, numbers

I have to read a rather large file, containing numbers, formatted in different ways.

I have tried using the builtin [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) function. This function works on some numbers, such as `22000.76`, but not `22000,76`.

Reading the comments on php.net have helped me a lot, I found this parseFloat function:

```
<?php 
function parseFloat($ptString) { 
        if (strlen($ptString) == 0) { 
                return false; 
        } 

        $pString = str_replace(" ", "", $ptString); 

        if (substr_count($pString, ",") > 1) 
            $pString = str_replace(",", "", $pString); 

        if (substr_count($pString, ".") > 1) 
            $pString = str_replace(".", "", $pString); 

        $pregResult = array(); 

        $commaset = strpos($pString,','); 
        if ($commaset === false) {$commaset = -1;} 

        $pointset = strpos($pString,'.'); 
        if ($pointset === false) {$pointset = -1;} 

        $pregResultA = array(); 
        $pregResultB = array(); 

        if ($pointset < $commaset) { 
            preg_match('#(([-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)+(,[0-9]+)?)#', $pString, $pregResultA); 
        } 
        preg_match('#(([-]?[0-9]+(,[0-9])?)+(\.[0-9]+)?)#', $pString, $pregResultB); 
        if ((isset($pregResultA[0]) && (!isset($pregResultB[0]) 
                || strstr($preResultA[0],$pregResultB[0]) == 0 
                || !$pointset))) { 
            $numberString = $pregResultA[0]; 
            $numberString = str_replace('.','',$numberString); 
            $numberString = str_replace(',','.',$numberString); 
        } 
        elseif (isset($pregResultB[0]) && (!isset($pregResultA[0]) 
                || strstr($pregResultB[0],$preResultA[0]) == 0 
                || !$commaset)) { 
            $numberString = $pregResultB[0]; 
            $numberString = str_replace(',','',$numberString); 
        } 
        else { 
            return false; 
        } 
        $result = (float)$numberString; 
        return $result; 
} 
?>
```

It works on almost all the numbers in my list. As I am using DKK as currency, some numbers are formatted like this: `Kr. 100.00`. This problem, I solved just be putting these lines in to top of the parseFloat function.

```
$prefix = substr($ptString, 0, 4); 
if ($prefix == "kr. " || $prefix == "Kr. ")
    $ptString = substr($ptString,4);

$prefix = substr($ptString, 0, 3); 
if ($prefix == "Kr." || $prefix == "kr.")
    $ptString = substr($ptString,3);
```

Now my problem only occurs on numbers, formatted like this `12.123.00`, which should be to `12123.00`

I *think* this can be solved with regular expressions (not my strength).

Basically, I'm asking to convert xx.xxx.dd to xxxxx.dd.

Dont think about rounding issues.

Comment: Don't use floats to store currency. You'll end up with rounding issues. Better to multiply by 100 and store it as a number of cents.

Comment: If you are on php 5.3, you can try [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

Comment: @Spudley,Rounding issues are not a consideration, since this is not critical.

Comment: @Carlos, I don't have NumberFormatter on my server, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your trouble is converting from xx.xxx.dd to xxxxx.dd, no need to use the regexp engine, you can just use the explode() function, for example:

```
$n = "123.456.78";
$a = explode(".", $n);

if(sizeof($a)==3) //had more than one dot
  $n = $a[0].$a[1].".".$a[2];

//$n now is 123456.78
```

Answer (score 2):

[`NumberFormatter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) has a `parseCurrency()` method that may prove useful.

Comment: As I do not have `NumberFormatter` on my php installation, this is not an option, though it would be the best solution.
Do you think it could be solved in regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

if the figures always have the fraction (pence, cents, etc).. try this hack:

```
$value = (float)preg_replace('/\D/', '', $strToParse)/100;
```